# Split own filename and assign specific parts to variables in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, scripting

thanks in advance for any help offered.

I have a batch file from which name i want to use parts and assign them as variables. Using the for `/f` with delims i was able to do something like it but i have to rename the file to a different scheme than what i need.
Se here is what i have:

-Current filename: **WHID-PRT-MFP-3, NORTH EAST OFFICE.bat**

```
SET getname=%~n0

for /f "tokens=1 delims=-" %%G IN ("%getname%") DO (SET siteid=%%G)

for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%E IN ("%getname%") DO (SET name=%%E) 

SET printername=%name%

SET servername=Server-%siteid%-01
```

OK, so that seems to work ok and im able to get the parts i need from the file name and assign them to variable so that `%name%=WHID-PRT-MFP-3` and `%siteid%=WHID`

Now my dilema is that i need the file name to be: `NORTH EAST OFFICE, WHID-PRT-MFP-3.bat`
So I've been trying to get the entire line behind the comma(`WHID-PRT-MFP-3`) to a variable and the first item in dashes(`WHID`) to another variable, same as the example above, but cant figure it out. This will be used with several names so not only as the example shown i could have shorter or longer names for both parts, say: `WHID-PRT-1, OFFICE 1`

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NORTH EAST OFFICE, WHID-PRT-MFP-3.bat:

```
SET getname=%~n0

rem split at comma
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%E IN ("%getname%") DO (

    rem trim space after comma
    for /f "tokens=*" %%S IN ("%%E") DO SET name=%%S

    rem get word before hyphen and strip leading space
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=- " %%S IN ("%%E") DO set siteid=%%S
)

SET printername=%name%
SET servername=Server-%siteid%-01
```

Comment: You sir/mam rule!!! Great answer exactly what i needed. 2 birds 1 stone actually... i didnt know i could nest for /f statements to keep splitting :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f  "tokens=1,2 delims=,." %%i in ("WHID-PRT-MFP-3, NORTH EAST OFFICE.bat") do set newname=%%j,%%i.bat
```